# doctrine orm count 1:n relationship on join

Tags: join, symfony, count, doctrine, query-builder

I am using doctrine orm with admingenerator module from symfony2 and I am unable to do a select count involving two tables. 
**I would really appreciate any thoughts on this. Thanks a lot in advance!**

This is the **querybuilder** expression:

```
class ListController extends BaseListController
{
protected function getQuery()
    {
        $query = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('q, count(f.fbid) AS no')
                    ->from('Shlomi\UsersBundle\Entity\users', 'q')
                    ->leftJoin('q.fbid' , 'f')
                    ->groupBy('q.fbid');


        $this->processSort($query);
        $this->processFilters($query);
                $this->processScopes($query);

        return $query->getQuery();
    }
}
```

The two entities I am using are:

```
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var bigint $fbid
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Friendships", mappedBy ="fbid")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fbid", referencedColumnName="fbid")
     * })
     */
    private $fbid;
   ....
```

AND

```
class Friendships
{
    /**
     * @var integer $Id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $Id;

   /**
     * @var Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="fbid")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fbid", referencedColumnName="fbid")
     * })
     */
    private $fbid;
....
```

Whereas the association annotation in Friendships has been automatically generated by doctrine:generate-entities (containing a foreign key reference of fbid from Users.fbid) the annotation in Users(1:n) has been inserted manually to best of my knowledge.

I have tried editing the query builder and annotation over and over again but in the end i get this :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony2\app\cache\dev\twig\ea\85\2b678090e942db52cc01e3950dbc.php line 225") in Admingenerated/ShlomiUsersBundle/Resources/views/UsersList/index.html.twig at line 92.

Thanks,
ion

Comment: It seems i was completely misunderstanding the annotations.
This page contains complete information for setting up the relationships however, it takes quite some brains to understand it:


[Associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html)

Comment: As doctrine as ORM works there is no need to count the records in the sql statement but from the objects, of the ArrayCollection attribute.

        $query = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('q,f ')
                    ->from('Shlomi\UsersBundle\Entity\users', 'q')
                    ->leftJoin('q.friends' , 'f');

Comment: Could you update the question with code from `admingenerated/ShlomiUsersBundle/Resources/views/UsersList/index.html.twig`? At least code around line 92.

Comment: As @Kosta said you should provide that template file in your question. Other that that, what type of hydration are you using in your controller. Array?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    $qb = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getEntityManager()
               ->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $qb->select('q', $qb->expr()->count('f.fbid'))
                ->from('Shlomi\UsersBundle\Entity\users', 'q')
                ->leftJoin('q.fbid' , 'f')
                ->groupBy('q.fbid');
```

This two-step process of making querybuilder ($qb) and then forming the query is important so you can use $qb methods (such as expr() and count() )